# НЕ работает scrollTop,скажите почему?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <body>
  <div id='elem'>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  a</br>
  </div>
    <script>
     let elem = document.querySelector('#elem')
     if(elem.scrollTop == '100px'){
     alert('Ты прокрутил 100px');
     }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это весь код? Если весь, то тут скроллится документ, а не элемент. И тут нет события скролла, на которое был бы повешан этот кусок кода. оформите вопрос нормально, чтобы вам помогли.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!